# C++ WinRT UWP XAML Data binding ItemsSource and SelectedIndex to IObservableVector<hstring> does not work

Tags: uwp-xaml, c++-winrt

I am using Visual Studio 2019 16.4.3, Microsoft.Windows.CppWinRT 2.0.200117.5, Windows 10 1809 Pro and targeting 10.0.17763.0.

I am trying to port a C++/CX app to C++ WinRT.  I am using data binding of the `ItemsSource`, `SelectedIndex`and `SelectedItem` properties of a combo box but I am running into issues.

For the `ItemsSource` I am binding to a `IObservableVector<String>`. The property is implemented using `IObservableVector<hstring>` and initialized with `single_threaded_observable_vector(std::vector<hstring>({L"One", L"Two", L"Three"}))`

When starting the application I am getting the following exception:

Exception thrown at 0x766B19B2 in BlankCppWinRT.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: winrt::hresult_no_interface at memory location 0x03AED210. occurred

Is this supposed to work? How do I data bind a `ItemsSource` to a collection of strings? This works in C# and C++/CX. What is the equivalent in C++ WinRT?

When I remove the two way binding to `SelectedIndex` the application starts and shows the three strings in the combo box, with an empty selected item. But when I try to set the selected index in code by `myComboBox().SelectedIndex(0);` (in the constructor) I am getting the same exception. Whereas the same line works in the `Loaded` handler of the page.

Details below.

Any ideas?

Call stack of exception:

```
    KernelBase.dll!_RaiseException@16() Unknown
    vcruntime140d_app.dll!_CxxThrowException(void * pExceptionObject, const _s__ThrowInfo * pThrowInfo) Line 133    C++
>   BlankCppWinRT.exe!winrt::throw_hresult(const winrt::hresult result) Line 4623   C++
    BlankCppWinRT.exe!winrt::check_hresult(const winrt::hresult result) Line 4700   C++
    BlankCppWinRT.exe!winrt::impl::as<winrt::Windows::Foundation::IReference<winrt::hstring>,winrt::impl::abi<winrt::Windows::Foundation::IUnknown,void>::type>(winrt::impl::abi<winrt::Windows::Foundation::IUnknown,void>::type * ptr) Line 1941  C++
    BlankCppWinRT.exe!winrt::Windows::Foundation::IUnknown::as<winrt::Windows::Foundation::IReference<winrt::hstring>>() Line 2026  C++
    BlankCppWinRT.exe!winrt::unbox_value<winrt::hstring>(const winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable & value) Line 2872  C++
    BlankCppWinRT.exe!winrt::impl::convertible_observable_vector<winrt::hstring,std::vector<winrt::hstring,std::allocator<winrt::hstring>>>::IndexOf(const winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable & value, unsigned int & index) Line 2547    C++
    BlankCppWinRT.exe!winrt::impl::produce<winrt::impl::convertible_observable_vector<winrt::hstring,std::vector<winrt::hstring,std::allocator<winrt::hstring>>>,winrt::Windows::Foundation::Collections::IVector<winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable>>::IndexOf(void * value, unsigned int * index, bool * winrt_impl_result) Line 566    C++
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!DirectUI::ItemCollection::IndexOf(IInspectable * value, unsigned int * index, unsigned char * found) Line 139   C++
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!DirectUI::ItemsControl::IsHostForItemContainer(Windows::UI::Xaml::IDependencyObject * pContainer, unsigned char * pIsHost) Line 1939    C++
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!DirectUI::ComboBox::IsHostForItemContainer(Windows::UI::Xaml::IDependencyObject * pContainer, unsigned char * pIsHost) Line 1239    C++
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!DirectUI::ItemContainerGenerator::ItemFromContainerImpl(Windows::UI::Xaml::IDependencyObject * container, IInspectable * * returnValue) Line 767    C++
    Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!DirectUI::ItemContainerGeneratorGenerated::ItemFromContainer(Windows::UI::Xaml::IDependencyObject * pContainer, IInspectable * * ppReturnValue) Line 222    C++
```

This is my XAML code:

```xml
<Page
    x:Class="BlankCppWinRT.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:BlankCppWinRT"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d" Loaded="OnLoaded">

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Button Margin="8" Width="160" x:Name="myButton" Click="ClickHandler">Click Me</Button>
        <ComboBox Margin="8" Width="160" x:Name="myComboBox" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Path=BoxItems}" SelectedIndex="{x:Bind Path=SelectedBoxItemIndex, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

This the .idl file:

```
namespace BlankCppWinRT
{
    [bindable]
    [default_interface]
    runtimeclass MainPage : Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Page, Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        MainPage();
        Windows.Foundation.Collections.IObservableVector<String> BoxItems{get;};
        Int32 SelectedBoxItemIndex;
        protected void RaisePropertyChanged(String propertyName);
    }
}
```

This MainPage.h:

```cpp
#pragma once

#include "MainPage.g.h"

namespace winrt::BlankCppWinRT::implementation
{
    struct MainPage : MainPageT<MainPage>
    {
        MainPage();

        Windows::Foundation::Collections::IObservableVector<hstring> BoxItems();

        int32_t SelectedBoxItemIndex();
        void SelectedBoxItemIndex(int32_t value);

        void ClickHandler(Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const& sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs const& args);

        void RaisePropertyChanged(hstring const& propertyName);
        winrt::event_token PropertyChanged(Windows::UI::Xaml::Data::PropertyChangedEventHandler const& handler);
        void PropertyChanged(winrt::event_token const& token) noexcept;

        void OnLoaded(winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const& sender, winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs const& e);

    protected:
        template<typename T>
        bool SetProperty(T& storage, const T& value, const hstring& propertyName)
        {
            if (storage == value)
                return false;
            storage = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }

    private:
        event<winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Data::PropertyChangedEventHandler> m_propertyChanged;

    private:
        Windows::Foundation::Collections::IObservableVector<hstring> m_boxItems;
        int m_selectedBoxItemIndex{};
    };
}

namespace winrt::BlankCppWinRT::factory_implementation
{
    struct MainPage : MainPageT<MainPage, implementation::MainPage>
    {
    };
}
```

This is MainPage.cpp:

```cpp
#include "pch.h"
#include "MainPage.h"
#include "MainPage.g.cpp"

using namespace winrt;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml;

namespace winrt::BlankCppWinRT::implementation
{
    MainPage::MainPage()
        : m_boxItems{single_threaded_observable_vector(std::vector<hstring>({L"One", L"Two", L"Three"}))}
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //causes exception
        //myComboBox().SelectedIndex(0);
    }

    Windows::Foundation::Collections::IObservableVector<hstring> MainPage::BoxItems()
    {
        return m_boxItems;
    }

    int32_t MainPage::SelectedBoxItemIndex()
    {
        return m_selectedBoxItemIndex;
    }

    // data binding to SelectedBoxItemIndex causes exception

    void MainPage::SelectedBoxItemIndex(int32_t value)
    {
        SetProperty(m_selectedBoxItemIndex, value, L"SelectedBoxItemIndex");
    }

    void MainPage::ClickHandler(IInspectable const&, RoutedEventArgs const&)
    {
        myButton().Content(box_value(L"Clicked"));
        SelectedBoxItemIndex(2);
    }

    void MainPage::RaisePropertyChanged(hstring const& propertyName)
    {
        m_propertyChanged(*this, PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    winrt::event_token MainPage::PropertyChanged(Windows::UI::Xaml::Data::PropertyChangedEventHandler const& handler)
    {
        return m_propertyChanged.add(handler);
    }

    void MainPage::PropertyChanged(winrt::event_token const& token) noexcept
    {
        m_propertyChanged.remove(token);
    }

    void MainPage::OnLoaded(winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const& sender, winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs const& e)
    {
        // works
        myComboBox().SelectedIndex(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean when you removed the two way binding to SelectedIndex in ComboBox, the app can run successfully, otherwise you received the winrt::hresult_no_interface exception? I used your code and run it, it worked well, I didn't receive the exception, can you show more details about the unexpected behavior? In addition, when you put `myComboBox().SelectedIndex(0);`  in the constructor, maybe the combo box Items collection is not populated, so the exception will occur, it's better to set SelectedIndex in the Loaded event handler.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. If I remove the two way binding to SelectedIndex in the XAML code for the ComboBox I do not get any exceptions. With data binding I am getting exceptions when starting in the debugger (one with default exception settings, two with C++ Exceptions ticked in the Exception Settings of Visual Studio.

Calling myComboBox().SelectedIndex(0); in the constructor cases exception in OnLoaded not.

When running the application and clicking on the button (setting the selected index to 2) I am getting and exception and the selected item in the combo box goes blank.

Comment: This exception is because XAML doesn't use IObservableVector<hstring>, it treated IObservableVector<hstring> as IObservableVector<IInspectable>. And the current item is null, when asked for the SelectedIndex, so XAML asks for the IndexOf(null), which fails because null is not a string.

Comment: So what is your suggestion? Using IObservable<Object> (IDL) IObservable<IInspectable>  (C++)? This is not nice. If I have a more complicated Item which is a runtime class I can use e.g. IObservableVector<BookSku> as described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/binding-collection . But not for simple strings? The reason for this is the different handling of boxing / unboxing strings for C++ / WinRT and C++/CX as described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/move-to-winrt-from-cx#boxing-and-unboxing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a stopgap fix, you could go to the Windows.Foundation.Collections.h to override the IndexOf() method. When unbox_value fails, catch the hresult_no_interface exception and return false. For more details, you can refer to this [thread](https://github.com/microsoft/cppwinrt/pull/522).

```
bool IndexOf(Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const& value, uint32_t& index) const
{
    //return IndexOf(unbox_value<T>(value), index);
    try
    {
        return IndexOf(unbox_value<T>(value), index);
    }
    catch (hresult_no_interface const&)
    {
        return false; // unbox_value failed, "value" wasn't even a boxed T
    }
}
```

Comment: I can confirm that this works. I used
`bool IndexOf(Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const& value, uint32_t& index) const
        {
            auto unboxed = try_unbox<T>(value);
            return unboxed ? IndexOf(*unboxed, index) : false;
        }
` so that no exception is thrown with try_unboxed from the mentioned thread. Thanks for your help!