# C++ WinRT UWP XAML data binding of SelectedItem to a property of type String / hstring does not compile

Tags: uwp-xaml, c++-winrt

I am using Visual Studio 2019 16.4.4, Microsoft.Windows.CppWinRT 2.0.200117.5, Windows 10 1809 Pro and targeting 10.0.17763.0.

I am trying to port a C++/CX app to C++ WinRT. I am using two way data binding of the SelectedItem property of a `ComboBox` to a property of type `String` \ `hstring` but I am getting a compilation error (see below).

Binding the `SelectedItem` property of a `ComboBox` to a property of type `String` works in C++/CX and C#. All this might also be related to

[C++ WinRT UWP XAML Data binding ItemsSource and SelectedIndex to IObservableVector<hstring> does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59987502/c-winrt-uwp-xaml-data-binding-itemssource-and-selectedindex-to-iobservablevect)

Of course I can use `Object` / `IInspectable` as type of the property (and type of the items in the items source) instead but this needs a lot of boilerplate code for converting to and from strings, searching the correct item in the items collection etc. I would like to avoid this.

Any ideas?

```
1>------ Build started: Project: BlankCppWinRT, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>XamlTypeInfo.g.cpp
1>D:\Dev\Samples\BlankCppWinRT\Generated Files\MainPage.xaml.g.hpp(172,50): error C2664: 'auto winrt::impl::consume_BlankCppWinRT_IMainPage<winrt::BlankCppWinRT::IMainPage>::SelectedBoxItem(const winrt::param::hstring &) const': cannot convert argument 1 from 'winrt::com_ptr<To>' to 'const winrt::param::hstring &'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            To=winrt::hstring
1>        ]
1>D:\Dev\Samples\BlankCppWinRT\Generated Files\MainPage.xaml.g.hpp(157,1): message : Reason: cannot convert from 'winrt::com_ptr<To>' to 'const winrt::param::hstring'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            To=winrt::hstring
1>        ]
1>D:\Dev\Samples\BlankCppWinRT\Generated Files\MainPage.xaml.g.hpp(172,107): message : No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
1>D:\Dev\Samples\BlankCppWinRT\Generated Files\winrt\impl\BlankCppWinRT.0.h(55,31): message : see declaration of 'winrt::impl::consume_BlankCppWinRT_IMainPage<winrt::BlankCppWinRT::IMainPage>::SelectedBoxItem'
1>D:\Dev\Samples\BlankCppWinRT\Generated Files\MainPage.xaml.g.hpp(157): message : while compiling class template member function 'void winrt::BlankCppWinRT::implementation::MainPageT<winrt::BlankCppWinRT::implementation::MainPage>::MainPage_obj1_Bindings::Connect(int32_t,const winrt::implements<D,winrt::BlankCppWinRT::MainPage,winrt::BlankCppWinRT::IMainPageProtected,winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Data::INotifyPropertyChanged,winrt::composing,winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::IPageOverrides,winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::IControlOverrides,winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::IControlOverrides6,winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::IFrameworkElementOverrides,winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::IFrameworkElementOverrides2,winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::IUIElementOverrides,winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::IUIElementOverrides7,winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::IUIElementOverrides8,winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::IUIElementOverrides9,winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Markup::IComponentConnector,winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Markup::IComponentConnector2>::IInspectable &)'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            D=winrt::BlankCppWinRT::implementation::MainPage
1>        ]
1>D:\Dev\Samples\BlankCppWinRT\Generated Files\MainPage.xaml.g.hpp(298): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'winrt::BlankCppWinRT::implementation::MainPageT<winrt::BlankCppWinRT::implementation::MainPage>::MainPage_obj1_Bindings' being compiled
1>D:\Dev\Samples\BlankCppWinRT\ObservableStringVector.h(31): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'winrt::impl::fast_iterator<winrt::Windows::Foundation::Collections::IObservableVector<winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable>>' being compiled
1>Done building project "BlankCppWinRT.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

This is the XAML code:

```
<Page
    x:Class="BlankCppWinRT.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:BlankCppWinRT"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d" Loaded="OnLoaded">

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Button Margin="8" Width="160" x:Name="myButton" Click="ClickHandler">Click Me</Button>
        <ComboBox Margin="8" Width="160" x:Name="myComboBox" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Path=BoxItems}" SelectedItem="{x:Bind Path=SelectedBoxItem, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

This my IDL file:

```
namespace BlankCppWinRT
{
    [bindable]
    [default_interface]
    runtimeclass MainPage : Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Page, Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        MainPage();
        Windows.Foundation.Collections.IObservableVector<String> BoxItems{get;};
        String SelectedBoxItem;
        protected void RaisePropertyChanged(String propertyName);
    }
}
```

This my MainPage.h:

```
#pragma once

#include "MainPage.g.h"

namespace winrt::BlankCppWinRT::implementation
{
    struct MainPage : MainPageT<MainPage>
    {
        MainPage();

        Windows::Foundation::Collections::IObservableVector<hstring> BoxItems();
        hstring SelectedBoxItem();
        void SelectedBoxItem(hstring const& value);

        void ClickHandler(Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const& sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs const& args);

        void RaisePropertyChanged(hstring const& propertyName);
        winrt::event_token PropertyChanged(Windows::UI::Xaml::Data::PropertyChangedEventHandler const& handler);
        void PropertyChanged(winrt::event_token const& token) noexcept;

    protected:
        template<typename T>
        bool SetProperty(T& storage, const T& value, const hstring& propertyName)
        {
            if (storage == value)
                return false;
            storage = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }

    private:
        event<winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Data::PropertyChangedEventHandler> m_propertyChanged;

    private:
        Windows::Foundation::Collections::IObservableVector<hstring> m_boxItems;
        hstring m_selectedBoxItem;
    };
}

namespace winrt::BlankCppWinRT::factory_implementation
{
    struct MainPage : MainPageT<MainPage, implementation::MainPage>
    {
    };
}
```

Comment: You could try to use [Converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.ivalueconverter.convert) to convert the hstring value to IInspectable value and return it. In that case, will the same issue occur?

Comment: You mean changing the type of the property in the MIDL / C++ code to IInspectable? Yes, that works and this is what I mentioned in my question. I do not need a Converter for this, I can use simply `box_value(hstring)`. But when setting the property from code I have to manually go through the collection of items search the correct existing one and use this object. Otherwise it does not work and the ComboBox shows and empty selection. I would like to avoid this code (and I do not have to write it in C# or C++ / CX):

Comment: This is the kind of code I have to write when setting the property that is bound to SelectedItem:
`IInspectable FindItem(const IObservableVector<IInspectable>& items, hstring value)
 {
  auto item = std::find_if(begin(items), end(items), [&value](const auto& item) { return winrt::unbox_value<winrt::hstring>(item) == value; });
  if (item != end(items))
   return *item;
  return nullptr;
 }`

Comment: If you want to avoid this code, it's better to use Converter. When you use the Converter, you can keep using IObservableVector<hstring> and hstring as type of property. In the Convert() method of Converter, you can return the IInspectable value to SelectedItem and in the ConvertBack() method of Converter, you can convert IInspectable to hstring to your property.

Answer (score 2):

Adding a converter as [Faywang - MSFT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11602935/faywang-msft) suggested works. There is no compilation error anymore and the two-way binding updates the `SelectedItem` property of the `ComboBox`.

Nevertheless, I find it strange that I have to do this in C++ / WinRT while it works out of the box without converter in C++/CX and C#. Moreover the issues described in [C++ WinRT UWP XAML Data binding ItemsSource and SelectedIndex to IObservableVector<hstring> does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59987502/c-winrt-uwp-xaml-data-binding-itemssource-and-selectedindex-to-iobservablevect) remain. When modifying the `SelectedItem` e.g. in the `Clicked` event handler of the button exceptions are thrown and the `ComboBox` displays an empty entry in certain cases.

This is the XAML code:

```xml
<Page
    x:Class="BlankAppCppWinRT.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:BlankAppCppWinRT"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Page.Resources>
        <local:SelectedItemConverter x:Key="SelectedItemConverter"/>
    </Page.Resources>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Button Width="80" Margin="8" Click="OnNextButtonClicked">Next</Button>
        <ComboBox Width="80" Margin="8" x:Name="boxItemsComboBox" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Path=ViewModel.BoxItems}" SelectedItem="{x:Bind Path=ViewModel.SelectedBoxItem, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource SelectedItemConverter}}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

This the IDL file of the `SelectedItemConverter`:

```
namespace BlankAppCppWinRT
{
    runtimeclass SelectedItemConverter : [default] Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.IValueConverter
    {
        SelectedItemConverter();
    }
}
```

And the implementation:

```cpp
#pragma once

#include "SelectedItemConverter.g.h"

namespace winrt::BlankAppCppWinRT::implementation
{
    struct SelectedItemConverter : SelectedItemConverterT<SelectedItemConverter>
    {
        SelectedItemConverter() = default;

        Windows::Foundation::IInspectable Convert(Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const& value, Windows::UI::Xaml::Interop::TypeName const& targetType, Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const& parameter, hstring const& language);
        Windows::Foundation::IInspectable ConvertBack(Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const& value, Windows::UI::Xaml::Interop::TypeName const& targetType, Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const& parameter, hstring const& language);
    };
}

namespace winrt::BlankAppCppWinRT::factory_implementation
{
    struct SelectedItemConverter : SelectedItemConverterT<SelectedItemConverter, implementation::SelectedItemConverter>
    {
    };
}
```

```cpp
#include "pch.h"
#include "SelectedItemConverter.h"
#if __has_include("SelectedItemConverter.g.cpp")
#include "SelectedItemConverter.g.cpp"
#endif

namespace winrt::BlankAppCppWinRT::implementation
{
    Windows::Foundation::IInspectable SelectedItemConverter::Convert(Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const& value, Windows::UI::Xaml::Interop::TypeName const& /*targetType*/, Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const& /*parameter*/, hstring const& /*language*/)
    {
        return value;
    }

    Windows::Foundation::IInspectable SelectedItemConverter::ConvertBack(Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const& value, Windows::UI::Xaml::Interop::TypeName const& /*targetType*/, Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const& /*parameter*/, hstring const& /*language*/)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```